# Tkinter Entry box to Text box

Tags: python, tkinter

What I am trying to do is after a user puts in their info into the `Entry` box and clicks submit their info will be displayed in the `Text` box to the right. I am having troubles getting the string from the one to the other.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("700x400")

def submitMessage():
    getEntry = enterName.get()
    txtBox.config(text=getEntry)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Submitted")

name = tk.Label(text="Name")
name.place(x=0, y=0)

enterName = tk.Entry()
enterName.place(x=0, y=20)
enterName.bind("<Return>",submitMessage)

'''
age = tk.Label(text="age")
age.place(x=0, y=50)

enterAge= tk.Entry()
enterAge.place(x=0, y=70)
'''

submit = tk.Button(text="Submit", command=submitMessage)
submit.place(x=0, y=120)

txtBox = tk.Text(height=20, width=30, bg="light gray")
txtBox.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: A `Text` widget doesn't have a `text=` option, you have to use its `.insert()` method to add text to it.

Comment: What does "having trouble" and "no luck" mean? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jasonharper said in the comments, you have to use the `.insert()` method to place text in a Text box. The `.insert()` method takes two arguments, the first an index of where you want to insert a string and the second argument being the string you want to insert.

Changing the line in `submitMessage()`:

```
txtBox.config(text=getEntry)
```

to

```
txtBox.insert(tk.INSERT, getEntry)
```

should achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. I didn't know about the tk.INSERT

Comment: @GoldenK: `tk.END` might be better. See [Text widget indices](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html). Either way, you might also want to delete the `Entry`’s contents first.